# Find usages const styled project

Tags: react-native, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, styled-components

How to search const that are not being used in my project from a styled-componet file?

```
export const Page(not usage) = styled(Container)`
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 16;
    padding-right: 16;
    background: ${colors.theme};
`;
```

Can be in visual studio code or intellij
**_______________________________________________________**

**UPDATED**

My style.js

```
// Not being exported vscode will detect
const Component = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
`;

export default {
    Component,
}
```

My page.js

```
import Style from './Style';

<Style.Component> </Style.Component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA reports const as unused unless it's imported in the other module:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just my suggestion. If you manage your style file separately and you call it up and use it,

Recall the style as a whole This softens the style not used in Visual Studio Code.

**Example**
[image: styles]

Comment: yes, but I didn't want to see in the component I'm using, but in the main file. Thanks for the sugestion